# QtCreator for Eclipse Users

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, qt-creator

I recently switched to QTCreator for C++ from Eclipse background.

I am looking for these two features in QtCreator...

(1) I want to open the file a class is written in by typing that class's name. For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in Eclipse.

(2) I want to move back to where my cursor were before the current operation.

Any shortcuts for above two features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To open the file of a class:

   - If you are in a file that is making use of the class, you can place the cursor on the class then press F2. By default, F2 is bound to the *Follow Symbol Under Cursor* action.
   - If you want to get to the class without to find an instance of it, you can use the [*Locator*](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-locator.html) . By default Press:

     - `ctrl` + `k` to access the locator
     - Type `c` then `space` to locate classes
     - Now type the name of your class. Once you've selected the class, hit `enter`
2. To navigate back to where you were, you can use GoBack and GoForward, as mentioned by Roman Zaytsev. These default to `alt` + `left` and `alt` + `right`. It has been many years since I have used eclipse, but I thought it also used `alt` + `left` and `right` as I was pleased to find QtCreator used it as well.

Answer (score 1):

> (2) I want to move back to where my cursor were before the current operation.

Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard. There assign shortcuts for "GoBack" and "GoForward" in "QtCreator" section.

Answer (score 0):

To go back to recent positions in the file / in other files, the gui has some handy buttons here

[image]