# Are there keyboard mapping layout files for popular IDEs?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, qt-creator, clion, keyboard-layout

I've been switching various C++ IDE lately. And every one of them has it's own key map. Are there any key map file repository to quickly import layout files for various IDE?

I'm used to Eclipse. Thus expect Ctrl+D to delete line, F5-F7 buttons to navigate in debugger, etc. Visual studio has mapped those to Ctrl+L and F9-F11. Qt Creator has no delete line by default. Each time it is manual mapping for each IDE.

CLion does a great job by including most popular IDE shortcuts. But for instance Qt Creator has only Import/Export feature. So maybe someone already stumbled this issue and has key map schemes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled only across it coming from Eclipse now using Visual Studio Code from time to time.

- Visual Studio Code -> Here I installed the Extension: **Eclipse Keymap**. At least feels a bit like home ;-)
- QT Creator -> I just googled but you can set the keys: [QtCreator for Eclipse Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128181/qtcreator-for-eclipse-users)